# Is it possible for jQuery to read CSS setting BEFORE any html components created?

Tags: jquery

I need to read CSS settings for the div's width and height etc in jQuery to arrange the divs (hundreds of them) in proper position in the page.

I know it is possible to read an existing div's actual size/position. But my requirement is to get the info before the div even exists. Anybody? Thanks!

Sorry, I didn't make it clear enough. Here is my situation:

I have a big parent div, which is going to hold multiple rows and columns of small divs.

The parent div is like 1000 x 1000 px. The small divs like 15 x 10 but it is configed in CSS, and its real value I don't know.

I need to calculate how many row and columns to array the matrix of divs. So that I can loop through to arrange them in the parent div.

Hope this is a better description.

Comment: oddly phrased question. You'd like to read an existing div's actual size/position before the div even exists?

Comment: It seems he's after a way to read the CSS properties from a CSS file to see which size the divs should have, and then do something depending on their size...

Comment: ever tried Masonry? http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry

Comment: He wants to specify the dimensions of a bunch of divs in a CSS, and then lay them out on the page according to their dimensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the compatibility page for [DOM CSS](http://quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html).  You should be able to access the rules of a stylesheet before any divs are created on the page, and without creating "dummy" divs.  For example,

```
var height = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.height;
```

That would show you the height value of the first rule in the first stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
var myDiv = $("<div></div>").css({properties});

$("body").append(myDiv);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the div does not exist, how do you intend to get some of its properties? If you're talking about setting attributes such as height and width on the fly *whilst* creating your divs that would be a different story:

```
var div = $('<div>Blahblahh</div>').css("height","100px");
```

Comment: You can create a new element and not apply it to the page yet.  Just assign it to a variable, and then wrap it with jQuery.  I believe he means "doesn't exist" as simply not on the page.